# Grails 1 to n relation find by Children

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have this two classes:

```
class Father{
  static hasMany= [children:Child]
}

class Child{
  String name
}
```

and In my controller I need to find if there is any `father` with an specific `child` but this does not work, asks for a set of children:

```
Father.countByChildren(Child.get(1))
```

Any suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Criteria:

```
Father.createCriteria().count {
        children {
            idEq(1L)
        }
    }
```